# Is "the" needed in "into (the) territory held by the rebels"?

Tags: definite-article

There is an example in [this link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/incursion):

> Government troops made an incursion into territory held by the rebels.

Doesn't "territory" need "the"?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to be about a specific aspect of learning English, using that sentence as an example. Also include what you already know about the usage of articles and why you're confused about this possibly incorrect sentence from a very reliable source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not need "the".  Do you know into which territory the incursion was made.

Perhaps if the rebels hold a small amount of land then "the territory" would make sense, since you do know which territory (it is the small area held by the rebels).

But if the rebels hold a wide area of territory, and you don't know where the incursion was made then you'd don't use "the".